# How to add a number in front & in back of the given number from the user? C++

Tags: c++

I'm writing a code, and I have to add the number "1" in the front and in the back of the given number from the user. For example, if the user enters 53, I want to change it to 1531 ( c++ ). Is that possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: number to string, put an 1 at front and behind and convert back to integer. Did you even try anything? How do you think it can't be possible?

Comment: There is also the (less intuitive) mathematical way `(x * 10 + 1 + (10 ^ (len(x) + 1)))` (in pseudocode).

Comment: Oh okay thank you, sorry I am very new to this and just starting to learn

Comment: @lucy if you just started to learn, maybe search in your book, tutorial or ask your teacher, how you can do it. In every good c++ book you come across "similar" problems

Comment: Do you have an idea how you would do it mathematically? Before you start something to implement it's always good to have a concept in mind (or better an algorithm).

Comment: A very simple way: [**Demo at coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aeb6c49659b19b9b)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple mathematical way. Note that there is an uncertainty about the way to deal with `0` input. Moreover, it only works with positive numbers (not a big deal to modify it to work with negative numbers).

```
#include <iostream>

int add_ones (int x) {
    if (x == 0) return 101;     // ??
    x = 10*x + 1;
    int prefix = 10;
    while (prefix <= x) prefix *= 10;
    return prefix + x;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    std::cin >> i;
    std::cout << i << " -> " << add_ones(i) << "\n";
}
```